# How to parse WSDL in PHP/Python?

Tags: php, python, soap, wsdl, onvif

I'm wondering if there is anything in PHP or Python which would properly parse WSDL files. For example i need to parse http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl. PHP SOAP extension generates code like this:

```
<ns1:GetStreamUri env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <param0 xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">StreamSetup</key>
            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Stream</key>
                    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">RTP-Unicast</value>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Transport</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                        <item>
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Protocol</key>
                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">UDP</value>
                        </item>
                    </value>
                </item>
            </value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">ProfileToken</key>
            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">main</value>
        </item>
    </param0>
</ns1:GetStreamUri>
```

And i need like this:

```
<GetStreamUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
    <StreamSetup>
        <Stream xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">RTP-Unicast</Stream>
        <Transport xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
            <Protocol>UDP</Protocol>
        </Transport>
    </StreamSetup>
    <ProfileToken>main</ProfileToken>
</GetStreamUri>
```

I'm already managed to generate request as in the second example through extending default SOAP extension, but still i need to add all types, namespaces and etc... which i dont know how to parse... So may be there is some way to generate this requests according to specifications provided in WSDL document?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing there is. Have you checked out SUDS, yet?
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Probably the most powerful SOAP library for python.

It works like

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client("http://example.com/foo.wsdl")
client.service.someMethod(someParameter)
```

Just search for SUDS on Stackoverflow and you will find tons of examples and further help.

Comment: yap. i tried it already, didn't work. Here is an example http://pastebin.com/7RX9fzBW